# When scrolling page, fixed div doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrolltop

I'm using this demo my project.
http://tympanus.net/Development/ArticleIntroEffects/index3.html

I want to do fixed menu after scrolling. And I use this js but it doesn't work.

```
    function fixDiv() {
        var $cache = $('#codrops-demos');
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100)
            $cache.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '10px', 'display': 'block'});
        else
            $cache.css({'position': 'relative', 'top': 'auto', 'display': 'none'});
    }
    $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
    fixDiv();
```

How can i make ?

Comment: Holy cow that header effect is nauseating.

Answer (score 0):

`codrops-demos` is a class, not an id, so you should use `.codrops-demos` rather than `#codrops-demos`.

Not sure that will be enough, though.

Comment: it is id in my localhost demo. I changed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/Pa36p/5/

JQuery (JS)

```
function fixDiv() {
    var $cache = $('#codrops-demos');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) $cache.css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '10px',
        'display': 'block'
    });
    else $cache.css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'top': '110px'
    });
}
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
fixDiv();
```

You defined the `display` of the menu to `none` when the window scroll is less than `100px`. So, the menu doesn't show up. If you are trying to do something like in the Codrops example, **you should only fix the menu when the scrolling is bigger than the distance between the menu and the top of the screen.**

---

### Cleaning your code

Here is a simpler and more readable version of the code you did, leveraging the browser's javascript processing by using CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pa36p/8/

JQuery (JS)

```
function fixDiv() {
    var $cache = $('#codrops-demos');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100)
        $cache.removeClass('relative').addClass('fixed');
    else
        $cache.removeClass('fixed').addClass('relative');
}
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
fixDiv();
```

CSS

```
.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
}
.relative{
    position: relative;
    top: 110px;
}
```

Comment: @MehmetDemiray You need JQuery for it to work. You don't have the JQuery library on your example

Comment: Yes i added new demo. if you want, check my codes.
http://www.foog.org/examples/1/

Comment: @MehmetDemiray you need to remove the `#codrops-demo` from within the `.title` element and put it between the `.bg-img` and the `.title`. The problem is that you cannot make an element `fixed` to the body when its parent is itself positioned `relative` or `absolute`.

Comment: @MehmetDemiray after doing this you need to reposition your menu to the desired relative position and its good to go ;)